# Query To Select One Record From Multiple Records

Tags: mysql

How can I write a query to get a table (the most right) in faster way if I want to select employers date "Dec-13" so the result look like this picture? Anybody help me?

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
  SELECT ID, Employer_ID
    FROM table
GROUP BY Employer_ID
```

Comment: @PhilipsTel If you find my answer correct, remember to mark with the tick on the left. Do it also with your previous questions !

Answer (score 4):

use `DISTINCT` to unique select values from the column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employer_ID
FROM   TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM tablename GROUP BY Employer_ID
```